# Vectorized Pixel Doubling Interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, interpolation, vectorization

I have an NxMx3 matrix of unit8s, with each (x,y,:) being a vector of RGB values. I'm trying to do pixel doubling interpolation by simply copying the east and south neighboring values over by one pixel.

```
eastNeighbors = [img(2:end,:,:)];
southNeighbors = [img(:,2:end,:)];

filtered = img + eastNeighbors + southNeighbors;
```

The problem with this is that I get a "Array dimensions must match for binary array op." error.

How can I add a row and column of [0, 0, 0] elements to eastNeighbors and southNeighbors, respectively?

**Edit:** Actually, shouldn't there be a way to implement this with filter2? This is basically the FIR filter out(x,y) = in(x,y) + in(x-1, y-1), correct?

Tried this:

```
h = [[1 1] [1 1]];

filtered = filter2(h, img);
```

Got "Not enough input arguments." error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you are after -

**Approach 1:** Using [**`nlfilter`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) for sliding-neighborhood operations

```
fun1 = @(x) sum([x(2,2) x(3,2) x(2,3)]);
OUTPUT_IMG = nlfilter(INPUT_IMG, [3 3], fun1);%%// INPUT_IMG is a gray image
```

**Approach 2:** Using direct summations by padding zeros with [**`padarray`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/padarray.html) to match matrix sizes

```
southNeighbors = padarray(INPUT_IMG(2:end,1:end),[1 0],'post');
eastNeighbors = padarray(INPUT_IMG(1:end,2:end),[0 1],'post');
OUTPUT_IMG = INPUT_IMG + eastNeighbors + southNeighbors;
```

**General Notes:**

If you are looking for `interpolation`, maybe you would want to find mean of those three pixels, so divide by `3`. Take care of the `uint8` datatype as it will clip off values at `255` when summing up.

Also, you might want to keep the last row and column same as in the original image, as they don't have both east and south neighboring pixels, so use this -

```
OUTPUT_IMG(:,end) = INPUT_IMG(:,end); 
OUTPUT_IMG(end,:) = INPUT_IMG(end,:);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. My initial approach was wrong as this ends up doubling the green values, but this will helpful for when I have to implement a bilinear filter.

Comment: I didn't know about `nlfilter`! I was using `blockproc` on 1x1 blocks with a neighbourhood, but this seems much easier to use

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah! It's quite a nifty tool and glad to be able to pay it forward as I learnt about this one right here on SO! Knowledge sharing at its best! :)

Answer (score 1):

To pad the images like you are interested in, you can use a combination of cat() and zeros() like so:

```
eastNeighbors = cat(2, zeros(size(img,1), 1, size(img,3)), img(:,2:end,:));
southNeighbors = cat(1, zeros(1, size(img,2), size(img,3)), img(2:end,:,:));

filtered = img + eastNeighbors + southNeighbors;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [convn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html), like this:

```
filtered = convn(img, [0 1 0; 1 1 0; 0 0 0]);
```